# R - rlang - Working with delayed evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, quosure

Trying to solve the following use case:
I have a full data set (`mydf`) which I want to `dplyr::group_by` with different variable sets according to the entries of another set of combinations of variables (`mysplits`). The issue is, my `mysplits` data.frame contains names of variables as characters.

There is a `dplyr::group_by_` option, but I'm hoping to achieve this with tools similar to the `rlang` functionality or something similar.

```
mydf <- 
    data.frame(
        var1 = c('x', 'x', 'y', 'y'), 
        var2 = c('y', 'z', 'x', 'z'),
        var3 = c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b'),
        outcome = runif(4),
        stringsAsFactors = F
    )

mysplits <-
     data.frame(
        g1 = c('var1', 'var2'),
        g2 = c('var2', 'var3'),
        stringsAsFactors = F
     )
```

I'm looking for something similar to:

```
dlply(
    .data = mysplits, .variables = (g1, g2),
    function(thissplit){
        group_by(mydf, f(thissplit$g1), f(thissplit$g2)) %>% summarise(mean(outcome))
    }
)
```

where `f()` is the missing component of my puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your data.frame of names has character values rather than factor levels

```
mysplits <-
  data.frame(
    g1 = c('var1', 'var2'),
    g2 = c('var2', 'var3'), 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
  )
```

Then you can use `group_by_at` with strings to choose column names. For example

```
group_by_at(mydf, c("var1", "var2")) %>% summarise(mean(outcome))
```

You can loop over values mapy different ways, but using other tidyverse functions rather tha plyr functions you can do

```
map2(mysplits$g1, mysplits$g2, ~group_by_at(mydf, c(.x, .y)) %>% summarise(mean(outcome)))
```

If you insist on using `group_by` and the rlang stuff, you can convert characters to symbols with `rlang::sym()` and then unquote those with `!!` so something like

```
group_by(mydf, !!rlang::sym(thissplit$g1), !!rlang::sym(thissplit$g2)) %>% summarise(mean(outcome))
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I'm not sure this solves my criteria. I've written a special version of `group_by` that I'm trying to call instead of `group_by` using the `rlang` principles. Is there a more generic alternative? Your second approach may work, but I'm not familiar with `map2`. I've added the actual function I aim to call in the question above

Comment: @jameselmore I've added another solution, but I couldn't get your code to run due to a syntax error so it's untested. I tend to avoid mixing plyr and dplyr and prefer to use other tidyverse functions. The function you added isn't all that helpful because there is no sample data to run and test it and no description of the desired output. You need to make it a proper reproducible example and show how you're calling it.